# Salesforce Certification in Srilanka

Tags: certification

How to do salesforce certification in SriLanka. can we do the examination online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have webassessor login to write exams. If not please create one from this [link](https://www.webassessor.com/wa.do?page=publicHome&branding=SALESFORCE)

You can take the exam in two ways

- Onsite
- Online

Please check [here](http://kryteriononline.com/host_locations/) for onsite location

Answering for your question, **Yes**, you can take online exam also. There are some set of rules need to be followed for online exam, you need a web camera for this.
So please read the exam policy before you register for the exam.

I prefer Onsite exam. This depends on you whichever you feel comfortable you can take it.

Below links will be useful for your exam

http://certification.salesforce.com/

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000186542&language=en_US

All the best for your examination.